# Stop mex function (C) without closing MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I want to stop the execution of my C code after I detected an NaN and send the error message to MATLAB using mexWarnMsgTxt.

The C code is executed from MATLAB over mex file. I tried to use abort() and exit() which indeed kill the c program but also MATLAB (I guess because it is the calling process here.)

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"


for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
       {
           if (mxIsFinite(out[i])) {

           }
           else if (mxIsInf(out[i])) {
               char *err_msg = malloc(max_len_err_msg);
               snprintf(err_msg, max_len_err_msg, "Inf detected in file %s at line %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
               mexWarnMsgTxt(err_msg);
               abort();
               //free(err_msg);
               //abort(1);
               /* NOTE: Test for NaN is here for illustration only.  If a double
                * is not finite and is not infinity, then it is a NaN */

           }
           else if (mxIsNaN(out[i])) {
               char *err_msg = malloc(max_len_err_msg);
               snprintf(err_msg, max_len_err_msg, "NaN detected in file %s at line %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
               mexWarnMsgTxt(err_msg);
               abort();
               //free(err_msg);

           }
       }
```

I just want my mexFunction to stop but not to terminate Matlab.

Comment: Have you tried using `return` or `break`?

Answer (score 2):

mex functions are normal C functions so, to leave the function early, just use `return`.

If you function allocated resources that need to be cleaned up manually, the established idiom in C is to use a `goto cleanup;` (this is one of the few, if not the only, acceptable and generally accepted uses of `goto`):

```
void mexFunction(
    int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]
) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        if (mxIsInf(out[i])) {
            char *err_msg = malloc(max_len_err_msg);
            snprintf(err_msg, max_len_err_msg, "Inf detected in file %s at line %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            mexWarnMsgTxt(err_msg);
            free(err_msg);
            goto cleanup;
        } else if (mxIsNaN(out[i])) {
            char *err_msg = malloc(max_len_err_msg);
            snprintf(err_msg, max_len_err_msg, "NaN detected in file %s at line %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            mexWarnMsgTxt(err_msg);
            free(err_msg);
            goto cleanup;
        }
        …
    }

cleanup:

    // Perform cleanup here.
}
```

(Note that in this code the `err_msg` cleanup is performed in its own scope rather than with the global cleanup.)

But in the case where no cleanup is to be performed, the `goto` statements are unnecessary and can be replaced by `return`.

Comment: What would I write then in the cleanup routine?

Comment: @hcl734 This entirely depends on what cleanup you need to perform, which in turn depends on what resources requiring manual management you allocated. I can’t tell you.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution is to define a global variable abort_flag in C, set it to 1 if the error occured and based on that break all my loops and return from the functions.
Kind of "manual" but works:

```
int  abort_flag = 0;
// to use in other file insert into header: extern int abort_flag;

// in the NaN case (see above)
abort_flag = 1;

// in the loops
if (abort_flag==1) { break; };

// in the functions
if (abort_flag==1) { return; };
```

Comment: What’s the purpose of the flag and the `break`? Why not `return` directly?

Comment: The flag is necessary imo to tell the calling function of the function containing the aforementioned for loop to terminate as well (short the for loop shown here runs in another for loop).
This is not the actual code, it is just to demonstrate what I inserted in other places, sorry for the confusion.